# Wait until useState object has value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I've made a custom hook, which can be used to fetch users location and find nearest marker on map based on that information.

Right now it works, but first object it returns is `useStates` default value. Response looks like this:

```js
{
  coordinates: { lat: '', lng: '' },
  loaded: false
}
```

After returning object first time, it starts to work like it should:

```js
{
  coordinates: { lat: 45.024335, lng: 19.277089 },
  loaded: true
}
```

So basically I don't want that the hook sends empty objects, with no values. How can I fix this?

```js
const useGeoLocation = (markers) => {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    loaded: false,
    coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
  });

  const onSuccess = (location) => {
    // User location succesfully fetched, converting data format.
    const targetPoint = turf.point([
      location.coords.latitude,
      location.coords.longitude,
    ]);

    // Fetching data from markers parameter and converting data format.
    var arr = [];
    markers.map((marker) => arr.push(turf.point(marker.location)));
    var points2 = turf.featureCollection(arr);

    // Calculating which marker is nearest to targetPoint.
    var nearest = turf.nearestPoint(targetPoint, points2);

    // Setting location of nearest marker to usestate.
    setLocation({
      loaded: true,
      coordinates: {
        lat: nearest.geometry.coordinates[0],
        lng: nearest.geometry.coordinates[1],
      },
    });
  };

  const onError = () => {
    setLocation({
      loaded: true,
      coordinates: {
        lat: 65.024335,
        lng: 27.277089,
      },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (markers) {
      if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
        onError();
      }
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
  }, [markers]);

  return location;
};
```

Comment: You can initialize location to null then it's just a simple check

Comment: What do you want it to return then? Since it's an asynchronous operation, you can't have the information right from the start. You also know that the information hasn't been loaded thanks to the loaded prop. So I don't quite understand.

Comment: What do you want the hook to send? You can not send data that you do not have. So you have to use a default value, for when the data is still being fetched. Whether that is `{loaded: false, coordinates: {lat: "", lng: ""}}`, `{loaded: false, coordinates: {}}`, `{loaded: false: coordinates: null}`, etc. These don't have to be empty, you can also use default coordinates, for example coordinates: `{loaded: false, {lat: 65.024335, lng: 27.277089}}` (coordinates taken from your error handling).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just returning the `location` object as a whole, you could split the return into an object with values for the data, a loading state, an error message if needs be. For example:

```js
const useGeoLocation = (markers) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const onSuccess = (location) => {
    // Rest of the success handler...
    setLocation({
      coordinates: {
        lat: nearest.geometry.coordinates[0],
        lng: nearest.geometry.coordinates[1],
      },
    });
  };

  const onError = () => {
    setLocation({
      coordinates: {
        lat: 65.024335,
        lng: 27.277089,
      },
    });
    setError("Some error message");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (markers) {
      if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
        onError();
      }
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
  }, [markers]);

  return {
    data: location,
    isLoading: !location && !error,
    error: error,
  };
};
```

Then when calling the hook you can do:

```js
const {data, isLoading, error} = useGeoLocation();
```

and check for the value of `data`, or that `isLoading` and `error` are false, before doing anything.